# Unterminated object at character 25691 of JSON Response

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

I am making an API call to get the base64 String of an image a user has uploaded, which I then use to display. Problem is, I'm getting this exception:

```
Unterminated object at character 25691
```

I understand that it is a large response, but sometimes my code reads the response and it works and sometimes it cuts off the last curly brace of the JSON response, which means I get:

```
{
 "objectID": 0,
 "isSuccess": true,
 "_ErrorText": null,
 "errorText": "",
 "objectTag": "Certificates",
 "newRegister": null,
 "objectItem": {
    "userDocumentID": 0,
    "Name": "Certificate",
    "status": "pending",
    "docTypeID": 0,
    "CdnName": "somepath.jpg",
    "ImageArray": "INSERT MASSIVE STRING HERE"
 }
```

where I should be getting that exact response, *only with an extra curly brace at the end*, to make it valid JSON. I have thought of catching that exception and appending it myself, but I don't want to put logic in a catch block. 
Here is my code for reading the response from the API:

```
try {   
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(r.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));         
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     builder.append(line);
   }

   //int read;
   //char[] buff = new char[1024];
   //while ((read = reader.read(buff)) != -1) {
   //    builder.append(buff, 0, read);
   //}

   JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
   finalResult = new JSONObject(tokener);

   response.put("isSuccess", finalResult.optBoolean("isSuccess"));
   response.put("errorText", finalResult.optString("errorText"));
   response.put("objectTag", finalResult.optString("objectTag"));
   response.put("objectItem", finalResult.optJSONObject("objectItem"));

 } catch (Exception ex) {
     this.HandleError(ex);
 }
```

If possible, please explain why such a call would fail at random? And also maybe what I can to do avoid this exception, please.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: obviously your JSON is invalid. I think that whatewer is giving you JSON works incorrectly. It is not Android problem.

Comment: Is it possible for something to alter the payload as it travels across the network?

Comment: who knows? That depends on maybe 100 different options of your network. As a beginning just start from using HTTPS.